# Use salt-local with `--file-root`, but include also your formula directory?

Tags: salt-stack

I do the following: `salt-call --local --file-root="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)" --file-root="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/formulas/firewalld-formula" --pillar-root="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/pillar" state.test firewalld`

This works fine for just the firewalld-formula directory to call the `firewalld` state. But the original root file is overwritten, so other states that were included in the original root are not found anymore. Is there a way to define multiple root entries? The man page seems to talk about a single path.

> ```
>    --file-root=FILE_ROOT
>          Set this directory as the base file root.
> ```

Putting everything in the same command switch makes Salt completely lost on where the state files are. So this doesn't work either `--file-root="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/formulas/firewalld-formula"`.

On the Salt master I can define multiple file roots:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /salt/srv
    - /salt/srv/formulas/firewalld-formula
```

How could I create a similar setup for the `salt-local` command?

Answer (score 1):

`salt-call` cannot define multiple roots. There is [an open feature request](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/64486).

Note that your proposed structure also has a major security issue. You have nested your pillar inside your state tree. This exposes the secrets to every minion if this were used on a salt-master.

Comment: > "Note that your proposed structure also has a major security issue."

Do you mean the merge request? Or that indeed I have the pillar tree in the same directory as the states?

Comment: I mean your pillar root is inside your file root. Therefore all your pillar is part of your fileserver.

Comment: Also, as you're using git, you probably want `gitfs` and `git_pillar` to avoid manually managing checkouts. But this question is about a masterless setup, which is a bit different.

Comment: Do you have some more information about that? How can I exploit such a thing. I've indeed read that the pillar should be separate somewhere. But SEO is so bad for Salt stuff, can't find it anymore.

Comment: @AquaL1te `salt-call slsutil.renderer path=salt://pillar/secrets/for-a-different-minion.sls`

Comment: Interesting, I still need to be root for that since the files under /etc/salt are not readable by regular users. And if this pillar file was in a different `file_roots` or something, then this wasn't possible?

Comment: The point is, if you're using a master, those secret files are on the master, and any minion process can read them. If the pillar root is separate then they can't.